# Do I *need* a TVS Diode at the USB connector?

Tags: usb-device, esd, tvs

I've got a typical electronic trinket that will be connected to laptops and wall warts to recharge.  Fairly cost-sensitive.

Will a spark completely destroy the MCU with a USB peripheral?  Is there a rule-of-thumb for how often this happens?  One in a million devices?  How standard is it to include these?

I'm considering something like [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/SP0503BAHTG/F2715DKR-ND/1154330) and I am welcome to more suggestions for typical USB peripheral devices.

Comment: Is this for a product or just for your own use?

Comment: @tcrosley, a product.

Comment: Can't answer for everyone, but I have never done it, and never had a usb port give problems with ftdi and microchip devices.  I'd be more inclined to add resistors inline to allow the catch diodes to do their work, and forget the tvs.

Comment: Note: there's a spark test in the CE testing for small devices. It doesn't matter how likely it is in the real world, it's a legal requirement to pass at least IEC 61000-4-2 tests if you want to sell in the EU.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you should have ESD protection on all external connectors, including power, USB, audio, SIM cards, SD cards, etc.  It is considered good practice to include them.

ESD damage has become more of a problem as the geometries inside IC's shrink, making them more susceptible.  I haven't seen any statistics on ESD damage, but I would guess -- and this is only an order of magnitude guess -- that for unprotected devices it is closer to 1 in 1,000 than 1 in 1,000,000.

[This device](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpd3e001.pdf) is less than half the price of the one you linked to.  It is available for 15 cents in 1000 unit quantities [at Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TPD3E001DRLR/296-21885-1-ND/1629244), and is especially designed for USB and other high-speed data applications.  Bedsides the three channel, it is also available in two, four, and six-channel devices.  I have used it in several commercial products which have undergone lab testing to 8 kV.